# SQlite to log transactions in a trading website

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've created the following code that allows people to add cash to their relevant login and update the relevant sqlite table for it. However when I get round to actually trying to log the additions to their account in a separate table, I end up with numerous issues. Here is the code:

```
    @app.route("/deposit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def deposit():
if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                amount = float(request.form.get("amount"))
            except:
                return apology("You must input a real number", 400)

            now = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + :amount WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"], amount=amount)
            db.execute("INSERT INTO acctransactions (id, acc_transaction, deposit) VALUES(:id, :acc_transaction, :deposit)", id=session["user_id"], transaction_time=now, deposit=amount["amount"])

            return redirect(url_for("index"))
        else:
            return render_template("deposit.html")
```

The first db execute runs perfectly fine, however I can't seem to get the second execute to run without it returning a variety of error messages (everything from unsupported value to missing placeholder). Do any of you know how I can successfully get this to write to the second table?

The second table has the following fields: id (int), acc_transaction (a timestamp), deposit (text), withdrawl (text), cash (numeric).

EDIT: With this particular set of code, I get the "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

If the code is replaced by: `db.execute("INSERT INTO acctransactions (id, acc_transaction, deposit) VALUES(:id, :acc_transaction, :deposit)", id=session["user_id"], transaction_time=now, deposit=deposit["deposit"])`

I get the error: "raise RuntimeError("missing value for placeholder (:{})".format(name))"

Comment: I swear I saw this question earlier today, with comments saying what you're doing wrong. Did you delete that one for some reason?

Comment: Edit your post with the message(s) and also the DDL for the acctransactions table.

Comment: If you're using named parameters... the names in the statement have to match up with the names in the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Needed to actually define and include a deposit line in the code.

```
app.route("/deposit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def deposit():

        if request.method == "POST":
            deposit = 0
            try:
                deposit = float(request.form.get("amount"))

            except:

                return apology("You must input a real number", 400)

            now = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0];
            old_cash = cash['cash']
            print('current cash:', cash)
            print('Oldcash:', old_cash)
            new_total = old_cash + deposit
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :new_total WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"], new_total=new_total)
            db.execute("INSERT INTO acctransactions (id, acc_transaction, deposit, cash) VALUES(:id, :acc_transaction, :deposit, :cash)", id=session["user_id"], acc_transaction=now, deposit=deposit, cash=cash["cash"])

            return redirect(url_for("acchistory"))
        else:
            return render_template("deposit.html")
```